# Получение координат и поворота одного объекта относительно позиции другого

Tags: c#, unity3d

Мне нужно получить координаты (Vector3, Quaternion) красных объектов относительно позиции зеленого. Чтобы потом при повороте/перемещении зелёного объекта, я мог воспроизвести красные объекты. См. картинки ниже. Использовать только вычисление через вектора и повороты. С вектором +- разобрался, а с поворотом - нет. Заранее спасибо[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Не совсем понятно, что вам нужно. Запомнить позиции и поворот всех красных кубов для каждого момента времени? Не лучше ли запоминать в какой момент какой красный куб куда провернул?

Comment: Представим: зелёный квадратик - это игрок, а красные - любые другие объекты на сцене. При выполнении определённого действия, нажатия на кнопку например, vector3 и quaternion красных квадратов полученных относительно позиции игрока сохраняются в пул и удаляются. Далее, появляется необходимость поместить обратно на сцену эти квадраты в таком же расположении по отношению к игроку, какими оно было при "сохранении". Вот мне и нужен способ получить значения векторов и кватернионов красных квадратов относительно вектора и кватерниона зелёного квадрата.